# The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly

Tags: java, android, admob

I do not understand how things aren't working, I've just completely removed ads for the moment as i want to make sure the game works in itself before i go putting other ads and such into it, and this just isn't allowing me to do so. This is my manifest;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.companyname.gamename"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        <!-- admob --><!--
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT"
            android:value="true"/>
        --><!-- admob -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name=".PTPlayer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.buildbox.consent.ConsentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <!-- ironsource --><!--
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        --><!-- ironsource -->
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

And the error code when connected to samsung device;

```
2020-02-26 21:54:31.520 21254-21254/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-02-26 21:54:31.522 21254-21254/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-02-26 21:54:32.350 21254-21254/com.redvenomstudios.toastrush E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.redvenomstudios.toastrush, PID: 21254
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6683)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxw.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:27)`
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6678)
            ... 10 more
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing same problem. I don't want AdMob enabled.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Removing AdMob's APPLICATION_ID from the manifest file is not enough to remove AdMob from your app.  You would also have to remove the AdMob dependencies (play-services-ads , play-services-base etc ) from your app build.gradle file.

### More detail:

But I'm sure you are already aware, removing those dependencies will prevent your app from building because your app still contains the AdMob SDK invocation code.

### Even more detail:

Since AdMob SDK v20 will break existing builds, (see https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration ),
I moved all my AdMob code into a separate library module.  This allows me to easily switch between SDKv19, SDKv20 or no AdMob( which is what you are after ).
I'm calling my library modules ADMOB_V19 and ADMOB_V20. I set a property and use that property in my project build.gradle file to do a conditional dependency.  Here is an example to try and make it clear on how to do this.

```
//-----------------------------------------------
// project build.gradle
//-----------------------------------------------
// Conditional AdMob - both false to remove AdMob
//-----------------------------------------------
ext {
    ADMOB_V19 = true
    ADMOB_V20 = false
}
//----------------------------------------------------------

app build.gradle
//-----------------------------------------------
// Load ONLY one or NONE, never both.
//-----------------------------------------------
if (rootProject.ADMOB_V20 == true) {
    println "*****************"
    println "*** ADMOB_V20   $archivesBaseName"
    println "*****************"
    api project(':appLib_ADMOB_V20')
}
if (rootProject.ADMOB_V19 == true) {
    println "*****************"
    println "*** ADMOB_V19   $archivesBaseName"
    println "*****************"
    api project(':appLib_ADMOB_V19')
}
//-----------------------------------------------
```

Now, I need a small amount of code in my app to call into either the ADMOB_V19 or ADMOB_V20 library.
For example,

```
J42Publisher_Helper helper = new J42Publisher_Helper(activity); // in ADMOB_V19
Publisher publisher = new Publisher(helper); // in my app
publisher.initialize();
```

Note to locations of those two classes. Publisher is in my base app and
the J42Publisher_Helper is in the ADMOB_V19 and ADMOB_V20 library modules.

The J42Publisher_Helper.class and all AdMob SDK v19 code is contained in the ADMOB_V19 library.

The J42Publisher_Helper.class and all AdMob SDK v20 code is contained in the ADMOB_V20 library.

No change is need in the base app when switching between SDK v19 and SDK 20.

To remove AdMob completely, I set ADMOB_V19 and ADMOB_V20 both to false and
remove those above 3 lines of code and imports ( and also Publisher.class since it is in my base app).

### Why?

Why did I go through all this?  Because SDK v20 is an app breaking change.  I needed to be able to continue to release fixes in my apps that use SDK 19 while at the same time work on migrating to SDK v20.

### Final details:

If you use Google's EEA/UK GDPR consent tools, put that code in the SDK specific library modules.  I know this was not an easy read and will be even harder to implement, but for me, splitting out the AdMob code was necessary.